# How can I optimize this nested query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I was hoping to get some opinions on a query that I wrote for work. In short, it uses a select and a few joins to show the data for an assembled part from a factory line. The query works great, but it takes about 40 seconds to execute, which is pretty useless when I am looking at multiple parts (one at a time.)

Is there anything I can do here to optimize it? The biggest draw I see that I can't control is that the "item_xref" table is not indexed, which slows things down.

The item table contains the status of a part, the model table holds the information for the item's model, and the item_xref table is for recording if any two parts are attached to each other. The result is: I scan a serial code on a part, it displays all components of that part, and then the description of the model for the components, along with date added and the station it was added by. This shows me in English what pieces are attached instead of a huge list of serial numbers.

I also have some parameters to hide certain stations and components like screws and clips which are recorded by the system, but fluff data that I don't need in a report.

```
select 
    i.ITEM_ID as "Components of Target", 
    m.DESCRIPTION as "Component Type",
    ix.LAST_UPDATE as "Time added",
    ix.LAST_USER as "Added by"
from item_xref as ix with (nolock) 
join item as i with (nolock) on ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID 
join model as m with (nolock) on i.MODEL_ID = m.MODEL_ID 
where ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID in (
    select component_item_id 
    from item_xref 
    where 
        item_ID = @variable 
        and COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like '1T%' 
        and COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like 'T4%' 
        and LAST_USER not like '%IMM%'
        and LAST_USER not like '%HST%'
    )
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: How many records do you expect, on average, as results of this query? Is it correct to assume they won't be more than a couple of hundreds? Is it allowed yo query snapshotted data, instead of live db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things in your query and DB design are surely to be fixed.

First of all, all tables should be properly indexed to achieve top performances. You wrote: *The biggest draw I see that I can't control is that the "item_xref" table is not indexed*.
Why you are not in control of this? Who is in control? For query to perform at best, it is mandatory all the tables have the minimum amount of indexes, at least for columns involved in join conditions (e.g. "join item as i with (nolock) on ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID", COMPONENT_ITEM_ID should be indexed, if it isn't the clustered index of the table).

**I strongly suggest you find whoever is in control of table(s) design to implement required indexes**.

I'll now work by successive iteration in search of optimal results. Some iteration may require permissions to alter table or create indexes, so, if you do not have them, find the guy how has.

**1st Iteration: Eliminate nested query**

Coming to the nested query itself, since it scopes the same table of the main query (item_xref), you can avoid it, getting rid of both nested query and IN clause, that is not one of the most performant operation in Sql Server. You can both transform it in a JOIN or just apply the conditions directly to the main query (which I prefer).
Your query becomes then:

```
select 
    i.ITEM_ID as "Components of Target", 
    m.DESCRIPTION as "Component Type",
    ix.LAST_UPDATE as "Time added",
    ix.LAST_USER as "Added by"
from item_xref as ix with (nolock) 
join item as i with (nolock) on ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID 
join model as m with (nolock) on i.MODEL_ID = m.MODEL_ID 
where ix.item_ID = @variable 
  and ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like '1T%' 
  and ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like 'T4%' 
  and ix.LAST_USER not like '%IMM%'
  and ix.LAST_USER not like '%HST%'
```

**2nd Iteration: Likes are not performant**

There are two kind of LIKE statements in your query: "Starts with" like (e.g. ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like '1T%') and "Contains" like (e.g. ix.LAST_USER not like '%IMM%'). Both aren't efficient, but the latter is one of the most unefficient things you can do in Sql Server :)
When you find yourself in need to use a LIKE statement, ask yourself what you are trying to accomplish.
It seems clear to me here you are basically *clustering* your records in specific groups.
With

```
  and ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like '1T%'
```

and

```
  and ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like 'T4%'
```

You are basically saying "I don't want records that are in group "Starts with 1T" or "Starts with T4". So basically you have categories of components, identified by the first 2 letters of their COMPONENT_ITEM_ID.
You have knowledge that these components are different somehow, and you should transfer this knowledge in your database design and in the client application.
But let's assume you cannot create a item_category table and create a foreign key.
You can still do something, provided you have permissions of altering the table and create a index: you can leverage the power of Computed Columns.
A Computed Column is not a phisical column in the table, but is computed using rules on the other columns every time the computed column is included in a read operation (like in "SELECT MyComputedColumn"). Fun fact is that if you create an index on a computed column, the index is instead actually persisted, and updated at each INSERT or UPDATE on the table.
My proposition is to create a computed column in item_xref table and create an index of it.
Let's see some code:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.item_xref ADD
ITEM_CATEGORY  AS LEFT(COMPONENT_ITEM_ID, 2)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ItemCategory] ON [dbo].[item_xref]
(
    [ITEM_CATEGORY] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
```

"Contains" like statements are trikier, but the same concept applies:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.item_xref ADD
LAST_USER_GROUP  AS CASE 
       WHEN LAST_USER LIKE '%IMM%' THEN 'IMM'
       WHEN LAST_USER LIKE '%HST%' THEN 'HST'
       -- add other cases if needed
       ELSE '---'
    END
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LastUserGroup] ON [dbo].[item_xref]
(
    [LAST_USER_GROUP] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF)
```

Doing that your query can become:

```
select 
    i.ITEM_ID as "Components of Target", 
    m.DESCRIPTION as "Component Type",
    ix.LAST_UPDATE as "Time added",
    ix.LAST_USER as "Added by"
from item_xref as ix with (nolock) 
join item as i with (nolock) on ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID 
join model as m with (nolock) on i.MODEL_ID = m.MODEL_ID 
where ix.item_ID = @variable 
  and ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID <> '1T' 
  and ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID <> 'T4' 
  and ix.LAST_USER <> 'IMM'
  and ix.LAST_USER <> 'HST'
```

This should be considerably faster than your original query (I suggest you verify with profiler and check execution plan).
Last note: beware the WITH(NOLOCK) hint, it is equivalent to READ_UNCOMMITTED, resulting in dirty or duplicate results. Once the query runs fast enough, you maybe won't need it anymore.

**Possible other iteration**

If you do not need to query the live data, but is sufficient to use data that is old of a specific period, you could schedule a database snapshot to be taken every {period} and query the snapshot instead of the live database. This way you won't suffer from any lock from write operations. This is useful in scheduled reporting, usually, when you have to build a report every day or week: you first create / update the database snapshot, then query it. Be aware, though: snapshot will take the same space of the master database DATA file(s), so check your disk space!

Comment: You are most welcome. Regarding index creation to be done during down time, obviously depends on hardware capabilities (recommeded fast SSDs for I/O operations), tables size, number of concurrent users and index nature (included column, modification of existing index vs creation of a new one), but some times can be done without bringing the DB down. I personally did it in production over 10+ million records table without a glitch from live website, but depends very much on your setup.

Comment: I tried this out and it does return the same result as mine. Thank you!

I had to delete my original comment so I could add some things, still adjusting to SOs posting rules.


So this gives what I need because the ix.ID = the i.ID in the join? Basically when the i.ID is scanned, the query follows the logic and actually looks at the ix.IDs instead? I want to make sure I really understand why it works.

 I'm still only beginning to really dig into SQL, and I really appreciate the advice of more experienced programmers.

Comment: Well, consider first my is not the only possible answer, nor maybe the best one. A lot (really, A LOT) of things depend on which indexes are defined for tables, size of the tables, types of columns, columns you want in the results, etc... Comments in SO are too short and limited to effectively explain how the query plan builder and executor of Sql Server work... For brevity, let's just say that how all this works depends on the execution plan that SQL Server creates from the query syntax. You can inspect the execution plan in Sql Management Studio, if you want.

Comment: There are a lot of resources out there that can explain things. One thing you can find interesting is https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-query-execution-plan-beginners-clustered-index-operators/ and related articles at the bottom of the page. HTH.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can change this to a join like this

```
select 
    i.ITEM_ID as "Components of Target", 
    m.DESCRIPTION as "Component Type",
    ix.LAST_UPDATE as "Time added",
    ix.LAST_USER as "Added by"
from item_xref as ix with (nolock) 
join item as i with (nolock) on ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID 
join model as m with (nolock) on i.MODEL_ID = m.MODEL_ID 
join item_xref as limit on ix.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID = limit.component_item_id 
        and limit.item_id = @variable 
        and left(limit.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID,2) <> '1T' 
        and left(limit.COMPONENT_ITEM_ID,2) <> 'T4' 
        and limit.LAST_USER not like '%IMM%'
        and limit.LAST_USER not like '%HST%'
```

Which depending on your optimizer might be faster.

However, the real slow part is going to be

```
limit.LAST_USER not like '%IMM%' and limit.LAST_USER not like '%HST%'
```

because of the wild card at the start it has to look at all elements and it can use an index

if there is a way to not use this filter I expect it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    x.component_item_id as "Components of Target", 
    m.DESCRIPTION as "Component Type",
    x.LAST_UPDATE as "Time added",
    x.LAST_USER as "Added by"
from 
(
    select top (100000) component_item_id, LAST_UPDATE, LAST_USER
    from item_xref with (nolock)
    where 
        item_ID = @variable 
        and COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like '1T%' 
        and COMPONENT_ITEM_ID not like 'T4%' 
        and LAST_USER not like '%IMM%'
        and LAST_USER not like '%HST%'
) as x
join item as i with (nolock) on x.component_item_id = i.ITEM_ID 
join model as m with (nolock) on i.MODEL_ID = m.MODEL_ID;
```